# Printing your output to cmd

Tags: python

Can you put your output in cmd for example

print('example')

and the out put will be in your cmd

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify what you mean by 'put your output in cmd'.

Comment: print by default outputs to cmd (it can be changed by supplying file=<IOStream>)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really clear, if you mean to simply put print() in your cmd as a command then no it won't work, in windows the [print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/print) command will send a text file to a printer.

But you can enter a python shell by typing 'python' in cmd and then you can execute whatever python code you want.

```
> python              
# Python shell
>>> print('example')  # Your python code
example               # Output
```

Comment: I'm new to programming and I know it was a dumb question but thanks anyways.